# SQL Server - Get only 1 primary key per day query

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Im trying to make a quote for my winform I have a total of 100 records. I created it like this

```
CREATE TABLE quote (
quote_id numeric identity primary key,
quote_quote varchar(500) not null,
quote_from varchar(100) not null,
)
```

Now I get the display I wanted when I display it in my winform, but I think that **everyday** a new quote would replace the other is nice, rather than just every run a different quote will display. I query it like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 quote_quote,quote_from FROM quotes ORDER BY NEWID()
```

How can I do that every day, that query will fire or any other suggestion?

Comment: Are You want to show that single quote for whole day, even user open and closed that windows application multiple time?

Comment: Yes. I exactly want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  One option is the following, which will cycle through a new quote each day:

```
 SELECT quote_quote, quote_from FROM QUOTE
 ORDER BY QUOTE_ID
 OFFSET (SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS INT) % COUNT(*) FROM QUOTE) ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

The subquery `SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS INT) % COUNT(*) FROM QUOTE` casts the current date to an integer (days since 1900-01-01) modulates by the number of rows in the quote table.  This will be a number between 0 and N-1, where N is the number of rows in the quotes table.  The query is offset by this number of rows and fetches only one row; the effect is to cycle through the quotes a day at a time.

Comment: Wow what a genius solution!!! Can't say anything anymore, the first thing that comes to my mind is trigger, stored proc.